# Testing class with Protected Constructor w/ PowerMock and Mockito

Tags: java, testing, mockito, powermock, robolectric

I have the following class to test:

```
public abstract class Challenge {
    protected int id;
    protected String name;
    protected String question;

    protected Challenge(){}

    public String[] toStrings(){
        String[] s = {Integer.toString(id), name, question};
        return s; 
    }

    ...
```

But using this test:

```
@Test
public void testToStrings() throws Exception{

    String[] expectedResult1 = new String[]{"1", "a", "b"};

    String[] obtainedResult1 = null;

    Challenge challengeMock = PowerMockito.mock(Challenge.class);
    challengeMock.id = 1;
    challengeMock.name = "a";
    challengeMock.question = "b";

    obtainedResult1 = challengeMock.toStrings();
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedResult1[0], obtainedResult1[0]);
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedResult1[1], obtainedResult1[1]);
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedResult1[2], obtainedResult1[2]);
}
```

I get a NullPointerException due to "obtainedResult1 = challengeMock.toStrings();" that returns null.

I use PowerMock + Mockito running in Robolectric with rule(becouse its an Android project).

```
@Rule
public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Why would you mock the class under test? Maybe you want to use PowerMockito.spy() or try to create an (anonymous) implementation of Challenge.

Comment: I mocked it only cos was easier to use the private constructor and to set the private data. Any tips for spy use, an example maybe?

Comment: FYI, although your question seems to have been answered by David already: a spy is similar to a mock but usually is used to mock or inspect certain behaviour of the actual CUT. You can use it like mock ([Mockito.spy(CUT.class)](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.5/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy%28T%29)) or with annotations. an equivalent method is offered by PowerMockito. I tend not to use powermock at all since I usually find its neccessity a sign of bad design i.e. non-testability. But that's personal taste.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I use powermock only becouse I have several static final methods and abstract class, so I can test them too. Btw I have a really near deadline so the solution with real_method is quicker. For the next project I'm surely going to better learn testing and using spy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need PowerMock for this; a Mockito mock will be just fine.  But normally, a mock has no functionality in its methods, which is why `toStrings()` isn't returning the value that you expect.  To change this, you need the `CALLS_REAL_METHODS` default answer.

So my recommendation would be to change the line where you create the mock (the third non-empty line of `testToStrings`) to something like this.

```
Challenge challengeMock = Mockito.mock(Challenge.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS );
```

I have tested this, and your test passes if you make this change.